# Print an NSArray in LLDB

Tags: lldb

What's your favorite way to print the contents of an `NSArray` using LLDB?

A python script? 
An inline for loop? 
An Objective-C method call?

I know it's easy to print an object by index. I want to print all objects at once.

Answer (score 10):

The description method on NSArray iterates through the objects in the array and does a description on them. No need to invent anything:

```
po [fooArray description]
```

Comment: Hi, Perhaps do you have an idea how to print similar object of type `CFArrayRef` from lldb ? I tried you method and got `error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.` thanks!

Comment: address=0x0 means you have a null pointer. try again with a valid one :)

Answer (score 1):

What version of Xcode/LLDB are you using?

In the 4.6 release which just went out, you should be able to just expand the NSArray in Xcode and have the contents displayed.
At the command line, doing

frame variable *myArray* --show-types -d run --ptr-depth 1

should also work.